# Warning: Uglification failed. Unexpected token: punc «:», expected: punc «,»

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-uglify, grunt-contrib-concat

I am using grunt and when building javascript I get this error:
`Warning: Uglification failed. Unexpected token: punc ":", expected: punc ",".`

The version of the grunt-contrib-uglify package is "grunt-contrib-uglify: "4.0.1",

And this is how I have it set in Gruntfile.js
`uglify: { options: { drop_debugger: false, preserveComments: false, sourceMap: true, compress: false }, admin: { options: { sourceMapName: 'admin/webroot/app.js.map' }, dest: 'admin/webroot/app.js' }, src: [ 'admin/webroot/assets/jquery/js/jquery.js', 'admin/webroot/assets/**/*.js', 'admin/webroot/app.js' ], filter: uglifyFilesFilter }`

How to fix this error?

I would like the error to disappear